# How can I extend my stay in the US for more than 90 days as an Australian Citizen

Tags: visas, australian-citizens

I am an Australian citizen and would like to stay in the US for longer than the 90 day visa, is there a way I can do this?  I do not have a profession so I cannot apply for a work visa.

Comment: What would you be doing with the extra time in the USA? Only there'd be a big worry that you'd be spending it working...

Comment: i THINK if you go to the USA consulate (I mean say in Sydney) you can get a 6 months visa.  NOte that the most common thing people do is, just go to canada or the carib. for a few days, and come back to the US - hence getting a new 90 day visa.

Comment: @JoeBlow: That is not possible. Please see [Can you re-enter USA on an ESTA?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/27741/can-you-re-enter-usa-on-an-esta) for example.

Comment: Great information Greg, I had no idea - things have changed in the last few years eh?

Answer (score 2):

You could look into a B1/B2 visa, which can be for tourist purposes, up to a period of six months.

[There is quite a bit of information to read on qualifications, etc](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/au/au-niv-typeb1b2.asp) but with the right documentation and evidence of funds, tickets etc, you could still do it.